# QML signal and slot between 2 different QML

Tags: qt, qml

I need to perform some actions in let's say main.qml according to button press in button.qml. Button inside of the button QML is inside of some custom object. Let's give it a name customObject. So customObject in button.qml looks like this:

```
customObject {
id:trialObject
signal backPagePressed()

Button {
id:button1
MultitouchArea {
onPressed:
{
   trialObject.backPagePressed()
}
```

Now when I press the button, it emits `backPagePressed()`. My question is: How can I make a slot for this signal in main QML? I'm familiar to signal and slot mechanism in C++, but that does not work for QML. I made something like this in main.qml:

```
Loader 
{
  id:pageLoader
  onBackPagePressed:
{
  pageLoader.source =""
}
}
```

That part needs to delete the Loader's source so that it will go back to page before. However, I'm not sure about `onBackPagePressed:` ... How can I connect my signal `backPagePressed`, to the related part in my loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `Connections` object (documented [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html)) together with the `item` property of the `Loader`:

```
Loader {
    id: pageLoader 
    source: "CustomObject.qml"
}

Connections {
    target: pageLoader.item

    //Qt < 5.15
    onBackPagePressed: pageLoader.source = ""

    //Qt >= 5.15
    function onBackPagePressed()
    {
        pageLoader.source = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: I created that Connection as a sibling to Loader. But it cannot find onBackPagePressed. Is it related to that signal is in another qml?

Comment: I meant child not a sibling*

Comment: you should set the `source` to be that CustomObject which has the signal. It can indeed be a sibling

Comment: How can I set the source? That is not stated in docs.. and I'm pretty new to QML.

Comment: @Amfasis you should update your answer to describe also new Connections syntax since Qt 5.15 like `function onBackPagePressed() {` instead of `onBackPagePressed: {`

Comment: Updated, thanks for that suggestion, I'm still stuck at 5.11 at my work, so didn't realize. @GünkutAğabeyoğlu I think it can be set a child as well actually, but I guess you figured it out by now ;-)

Comment: @Amfasis Yep I did :)) thanks for the help